# Relationship between solutions of two matrix differential equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Given a ($4\times4$ in the important case) matrix differential equation:

$\frac{d U_t}{dt}= A_t U_t$

where $U_t \in SU(n)$ and $A_t \in \mathfrak{su}(n)$.

What is the relationship between the solution $U_t$ to this equation and the solution to:

$\frac{d U_t}{dt}=f(t)A_tU_t$ where $f$ is some not too badly behaved real function? Can the new solution be easily expressed in terms of the old one?

Comment: Well, it would be much simpler if you were asking about relationship between solutions of $\frac{d U_t}{dt} = A_t U_t$ and $\frac{d U_t}{dt} = f(U_t) A_t U_t$ , but that's not the case you are interested in, right?

Comment: No, this is not what I meant unfortunately!